# Create subset of multiple pandas dataframes using for statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with multiple dataframes in pandas, and am looking to only select certain columns from each of them.

```
AUD = [AUD2yr,AUD5yr,AUD10yr,AUD30yr]

for df in AUD:
    df = df[['Date','Open']]
```

I would ideally like to keep the names of the dataframes, but i receive the following error:

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

This means in your program somewhere `None[...]` is attempted. From the snippet you shared, that happens with `df[...]`, i.e., somehow `df` became `None`.

Apart from that, doing `df = df[["Date", "Open"]]` inside the loop body will *not* alter the frames in the list; rather, it makes `df` now "look" at a new frame; the reference to the frame in the list is lost.

To fix that, you can traverse the list along with the index and modify with indexing:

```py
for idx, frame in enumerate(AUD):
    AUD[idx] = frame[["Date", "Open"]]
```

or perhaps better, with a list comprehension:

```py
AUD = [frame[["Date", "Open"]] for frame in AUD]
```

Lastly, to avoid the infamous SettingWithCopyWarning in case you further modify the frames, it's better you put `.copy()` after subsetting, e.g.,

```py
AUD = [frame[["Date", "Open"]].copy() for frame in AUD]
```

---

Additionally, to affect the individual variables inside the list, i.e., `AUD*yr` vars in `AUD = [AUD2yr, AUD5yr, AUD10yr, AUD30yr]`, there are some ways:

- We can go for `inplace=True` option in operations we do. Note that this is not always possible; but in your specific case, we'll use `.drop` method which supports this, and we will drop all but "Date" and "Open" columns, so here we go:

```py
for idx, frame in AUD:
    cols_to_drop = frame.columns.difference(["Date", "Open"])
    AUD[idx].drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
```

^this approach is infeasible with a list comprehension. But that brings us to 2nd option:

- If there is handful of frames in the list, like you have 4 in `AUD`, we can unpack the new list again to those variables:

```py
AUD2yr, AUD5yr, AUD10yr, AUD30yr = AUD = [frame[["Date", "Open"]].copy()
                                          for frame in AUD]
```

This will now not only alter `AUD` but also the individual variables. First option also does that, so your choice :)

- There's a 3rd alternative... But that requires you to change `AUD` to be a *dictionary* rather than a list. This way you won't refer to the frames as bareword variables like `AUD10yr` but rather as dictionary keys, e.g., `AUD["AUD10yr"]`. For what it's worth, this might be a better practice if you got a lot frames especially. So,

```py
# initialize as dictionary
AUD = {"AUD2yr": AUD2yr, "AUD5yr": AUD5yr, "AUD10yr": AUD10yr, "AUD30yr": AUD30yr}

# modify via dict comprehension, akin to list comprehension in the very above
AUD = {frame_name: frame[["Date", "Open"]].copy()
       for frame_name, frame in AUD.items()}

# now, can refer to individuals as:
print(AUD["AUD5yr"])
```

---

Some references:

- How "names" work in Python, regarding to `df = df[...]` not altering the originals: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1/names1.html
- On the SettingWithCopyWarning: [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)
- List comprehensions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
- Variable variables: [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however trying all of the methods above I am not able to call on each dataframe individually. In your examples, by printing AUD, it prints the dataframes as requested, but I cant print the individual dataframe. So when I print AUD2yr,  it will still print all of the columns and not just the "Date" and "Open" column. Is there any way that I can get this from the AUD list? Thanks again

Comment: hi @Jack, I see what you mean (hopefully...) and presented 2 and a half ways to achieve that, I hope it helps (it starts at "Additionally" part)